# split payments using stripe in django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, payment

I am working on a project where, buyer will make the payment and that payment should be split into

- application-fee
- seller payment
- referral payment
  her is my code

```
        if buyer_address.state.lower() == 'alabama' or buyer_address.state.lower() == 'al':
            taxes = int(round(float(price * 0.08)))
        shipping_charges = courier.price
        total_charges = price + taxes
        # if referrals:
        admin_amount = int((total_charges - shipping_charges) * 0.2)
        seller_amount = total_charges - admin_amount
        referral_amount = int(admin_amount * 0.02)
        payment_info = {
            "amount": total_charges,  # Amount in cents
            "currency": "usd",
            "connected_accounts": [
                {"account_id": 'acct_1OoODQIbLDChIvG2', "amount": seller_amount},
                {"account_id": "acct_1OrzPRI5g3KKKWKv", "amount": referral_amount},
            ]
        }

        stripe.api_key = "sk_test_EI5Kddsg2MCELde0vbX2cDGw"
        try:
            for account_info in payment_info["connected_accounts"]:
                # Set up transfer amount and destination separately
                transfer_amount = account_info["amount"]
                destination_account = account_info["account_id"]
                print("=======================================================", destination_account)
                
                session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                    success_url=my_domain + '/payment_success/' + str(auction_id) + '/' + courier_id + "?mode=" + mode,
                    cancel_url=my_domain + '/payment_failed/' + str(auction_id) + '/' + courier_id + "?mode=" + mode,
                    payment_method_types=['card'],
                    mode = 'payment',
                   line_items=[{
                        'price_data': {
                            'currency': 'usd',
                            'product_data': {
                                'name': 'NailSent Nails',
                            },
                            'unit_amount': int(total_charges),  # amount should be in cents
                        },
                        'quantity': 1,
                    }],
                    payment_intent_data={
                        'transfer_data': {
                            'destination': destination_account,
                            'amount': transfer_amount,  # amount should be in cents
                        }
                    },
                )
        except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
            return HttpResponse(f"Error: {e}")
```

i was trying to split the payment between all three user

- application-fee
- seller charges
- referral charges

i tried to user payment transfer method but got the error of insufficient funds

Right now if i make the payment. referral amount goes to the referral account but seller doesn't receive any money

please provide any best solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: To split payments in Django using Stripe, calculate fees and amounts for application, seller, and referral. Create a payment intent with the total amount, specifying the application fee and transfer data for the seller's account. Use Stripe's Transfer API to handle the referral payment. Implement Stripe Checkout session with the payment intent. Ensure proper error handling for Stripe errors. This approach ensures accurate distribution of funds to all parties involved

Answer (score 1):

You can use [separate Charges and Transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers) to split payments between multiple Connected Accounts. Notice the use of the `transfer_group` [property](https://docs.stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-transfer_group), which allows you to specify the source Charge for the Transfers. It will help you avoid the Insufficient funds error. This way the Transfers will only be executed when the original Charge succeeds.

Comment: I have tried this way but still getting insufficient funds error

Comment: that's because `transfer_group` doesn't actually help with this. `source_transaction` does:
https://docs.stripe.com/connect/separate-charges-and-transfers

Comment: `transfer_group` should work too as long as the source PaymentIntents are marked with it too: https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-transfer_group